# how to web-scrape from a table?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am working on a project where I have to web-scrape from the site https://lite.ip2location.com.
When you come into the site there are a number of `div`s each with a different country. When you click on one of them the browser is redirected to a table on that site.  The table has a `thead` and `tbody`.   I need to access the `tbody` but for some reason, I only get the information from the `thead` tag.

This is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String url = "https://lite.ip2location.com/ip-address-ranges-by-country";
        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            for (Element element : document.select("div.card-columns div")) {
                Elements link = element.select("a");
                String redirectUrl = "https://lite.ip2location.com" + link.attr("href");
                final Document redirectDoc = Jsoup.connect(redirectUrl).get();
                Element table = redirectDoc.select("table").get(0);
                for (Element row : table.select("tbody tr")) {
                    System.out.println(row.text());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to scrape the pages? You can sign up for the free DB1 LITE database which consists of all the information in one CSV file.

Comment: @MichaelC. its for a school project we have to web-scrape using jsoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup just parses HTML from a URL it does not execute JavaScript or fetches additional resources such as js or css files.

At a page with IP address ranges for a country data represented in JSON that is loaded asynchronously by a browser and then with that data a table is populated.

Here `final Document redirectDoc = Jsoup.connect(redirectUrl).get();` you got an HTML page that contains only a template for a table. Like this

```
<div class="row my-5" style="min-height:500px;">
    <div class="col table-responsive">
        <table id="ip-address" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="30%" class="no-sort">Begin IP Address</th>
                    <th width="30%" class="no-sort">End IP Address</th>
                    <th width="40%" class="text-right no-sort">Total Count</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And exactly this fragment you parses in your code.

So, there is a one of a possible solution to get ranges.

The data with IP address ranges for Zimbabwe locates at URLs like this `https://cdn-lite.ip2location.com/datasets/ZW.json` . A file name matches with Country Codes Alpha-2 (ZW for Zimbabwe).

These codes for available countries can be extracted from `https://lite.ip2location.com/ip-address-ranges-by-country` page where inside a `<p class="card-text">` tag for each country there is a `span` tag to draw a flag.

The second class contains a code at the end of the name (flag-icon-**ba**)

```
<div class="card" style="min-height:72px;">
    <div class="card-body" style="padding:.85rem;">
        <p class="card-text"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ba"></span> <a href="/bosnia-and-herzegovina-ip-address-ranges">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

BA for Bosnia and Herzegovina.

Having a URL to a JSON data for a particular country, you can fetch it with Jsoup.

```
String data = Jsoup
        .connect("https://cdn-lite.ip2location.com/datasets/BA.json")
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .get().text();
```